# Why is it pausing after the song it played?

Tags: ios, swift

I am getting preview songs from itunes api and it plays, but when I click the button again to pause it, the song has to finish only then it will pause (it prints "paused" in the console). How do I fix this?

```
  func playit(sender: UIButton!) {

    let playButtonrow = sender.tag

    print(ret[playButtonrow])
    switch(buttonState){
    case 0:
    let searchTerm: String = ret[playButtonrow]

    let itunesSearchTerm = searchTerm.stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString(" ", withString: "+", options: NSStringCompareOptions.CaseInsensitiveSearch, range: nil)

   if let escapedSearchTerm = itunesSearchTerm.stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding) {
    let urlPath = "https://itunes.apple.com/search?term=\(escapedSearchTerm)&media=music"
    let url: NSURL = NSURL(string: urlPath)!
    let request: NSURLRequest = NSURLRequest(URL: url)
    let ctn: NSURLConnection = NSURLConnection(request: request, delegate: self, startImmediately: false)!


    print("Search iTunes API at URL \(url)")

    ctn.start()

    let task = NSURLSession.sharedSession().dataTaskWithURL(url) {(data, response, error) -> Void in
        do {
            if let dict: NSDictionary = try NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(data!, options: NSJSONReadingOptions.MutableContainers) as? NSDictionary
            {


                let previewUrl = NSURL(string: (dict["results"]![0]["previewUrl"] as? String)!)!
                        print(previewUrl)
                player = AVPlayer(URL: previewUrl) 
                player.rate = 1.0
                player.play()



            }

        } catch let jsonError as NSError {

        }
    }
    task.resume()

    }
        buttonState = 1;
        break


    case 1:
    player.pause()
    print("player paused")
    buttonState = 0
    default: break

}

}
```

Comment: I don't know what the problem is, but you can delete the lines contain `request` and `ctn`. They're not helping.

Comment: The song playing in the avplayer has to finish, only then will the player pause.